# How to get AtomicInteger to work in a Runnable class

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicinteger

I wrote this code as a `Runnable` in Java, but my professor wants me to add `AtomicInteger` so that there is no thread interference. How do I go about doing that? I have tried looking up examples of how to use it in code but I have no idea what to do in this case.

```java
public class GarageWorker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("We are going to count the vehicles in the garage");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("There are 50 vehicles in the garage to start with!");
        System.out.println();

        GarageWorker garage = new GarageWorker(50);

        Runnable vehicleEnter = garage.new Enter();
        Runnable vehicleExit = garage.new Exit();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(vehicleEnter);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(vehicleExit);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }

    public GarageWorker(int initialCarCount) {
        counter = initialCarCount;
    }

    public int counter;

    public class Enter implements Runnable {
        public Enter() {

        }

        public int increaseVehicleCount() {
            return ++counter;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (counter < 100) {
                System.out.println("One vehicle entered the garage now there are " + increaseVehicleCount());
            }
        }
    }

    public class Exit implements Runnable {
        public Exit() {

        }

        public int decreaseVehicleCount() {
            return --counter;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (counter > 0) {
                System.out.println("One vehicle left the garage now there are " + decreaseVehicleCount());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs fine, but my professor wants me to implement the `AtomicInteger` class into the code.

Comment: So, you want to instantiate your `GarageWorker` and make the `counter` instance variable of type `AtomicInteger`. Can you provide an example of how you want to go about this at the bottom of your post?

Comment: Yes so that instead of using the garage counter I replace it with the AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your professor wants you to change `counter` to an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). First you want to import `AtomicInteger` as well as change the declaration of `counter` and the constructor to reflect that.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
```

```java
public GarageWorker(int initialCarCount) {
    counter = new AtomicInteger(initialCarCount);
}

public AtomicInteger counter;
```

Also, you want to change the `increaseVehicleCount` and `decreaseVehicleCount` methods in order to use `AtomicInteger` instead of `int`.

```java
public int increaseVehicleCount() {
    return counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

```java
public int decreaseVehicleCount() {
    return counter.decrementAndGet();
}
```

[`incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--) as well as [`decrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#decrementAndGet--) do just as they say: they increment (or decrement) and subsequently returns the new value. For more information, take a look at [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Cheers!